# Moving files between libraries removes the files metadata

Tags: content-type, metadata

My understanding was that when a file is assigned to a content type, the metadata was linked to the file and not the library.

I try to move files between different document libraries. But when I do this I lose the metadata linked to these files. The following message shows up when i try:

> The file or folder contains properties that will be lost at the new
>   destination

I had to first add the Content Type to the new library in order not to lose the metadata.

Should it be this way or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you're seeing is correct and expected behavior. The Content Type must be on the destination Library.